# Relative URL resolution for Microdata properties

Tags: html, microdata, relative-urls

The HTML Microdata Working Draft [shows the following example](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#typed-items):

> Assuming a page at `http://example.net/some/dataexample` contains the following code:
>
> ```html
> <section itemscope itemtype="http://example.org/animals#cat">
>  <h1 itemprop="name">Hedral</h1>
>  <p itemprop="desc">Hedral is a male american domestic
>  shorthair, with a fluffy black fur with white paws and belly.</p>
>  <img itemprop="img" src="hedral.jpeg" alt="" title="Hedral, age 18 months">
> </section>
> ```
>
> The item's type is "`http://example.org/animals#cat`"
>
> In this example the "`http://example.org/animals#cat`" item has three properties:
>
> **`http://example.org/animals#name`**
>       "Hedral"
>
> **`http://example.org/animals#desc`**
>       Hedral is a male american domestic shorthair, with a fluffy black fur with white paws and belly.
>
> **`http://example.org/animals#img`**
>       hedral.jpeg

I'm confused as to **why the `name` property, resolves to `http://example.org/animals#name`?**

I thought that Microdata used standard relative URL resolution for this purpose, in which case AFAIK it should be `http://example.org/name`.

Is this a documentation bug or is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itemprop` isn’t a regular hyperlink attribute (like `href` or `src`). It can contain absolute URLs and/or strings, but not relative URLs.

If the value is a string, the property URL gets formed by appending this string to the vocabulary identifier.

This vocabulary identifier gets determined by the `itemscope` attribute. [There are three cases](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-microdata-20180426/#dfn-vocabulary-identifier):

- If the `itemscope` value contains a `#`,
  the `itemprop` value will be appended after the first `#`.
- If the `itemscope` value contains a `/` (and no `#`),
  the `itemprop` value will be appended after the last `/`.
- If the `itemscope` value contains no `#` and no `/`,
  a `/` will be added and the `itemprop` value will be appended after this `/`.